# Wordpress Image Mapper How to make are to be always highlithed

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I do have an wordpress website with Image Mapper, and where i have a picture with area i want the highlithed area to stay on. Right now it is showing only when i move my mouse over that place.
Here is that site: http://multis.naszastrona.eu/pietro-6/
and here is the .js code:
http://pastebin.com/21rKPAwr
I tried few thing but they are not working (editing the code). But i think i made something wrong.

Comment: onMouseover to onLoad

Comment: I changed onMouseover here on onLoad byt nothing happen: http://pastebin.com/ZDB45p7Y